# Matlab eventually crashes with mex callback

Tags: c, matlab, crash, mex

I have a Mex function that forwards specific messages and message types (1,2,3) from C to the Matlab function 'fruit_getpar.m'. This Matlab function 'fruit_getpar.m' extracts parameters from the message string and stores it as variables. The C messages are generated at random instances. The problem: Matlab crashes sometimes with generated C messages, althuogh the structure of this message is allways the same.

any clues?

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "fruit_matlab.h"
#include "string.h"

// Callback function
    void fruit_mexCallback(char *message, double message_type){
    mxArray *lhs[2];
    char sType[5];

    if (message == NULL || message_type <= 0)
          return;

    if (strstr(message, "apple") == NULL && strstr(message, "banana") == NULL && strstr(message, "orange") == NULL) {
    itoa((int)message_type, sType, 10);
    lhs[0] = mxCreateString(message);
    lhs[1] = mxCreateString(sType);
    mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 2, lhs, "fruit_getpar");
    mxDestroyArray(lhs[0]);
    mxDestroyArray(lhs[1]);
    }
    return;  
    }

// MEX Gateway
    void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]){
    //pointer to callback function
    void (*cbPtr)() = NULL;
    cbPtr = fruit_mexCallback;
    Register_Callback(cbPtr);
    }
```

Comment: In general, a runtime exception in C will crash MATLAB mex. For example, an illegal read.

Comment: what could an illegal read be in this context?

Comment: Out of bounds, uninitialized, etc. Anything that gives a runtime error really.

Answer (score 1):

in

```
void (*cbPtr)() = NULL;
cbPtr = fruit_mexCallback;
Register_Callback(cbPtr);
```

fruit_mexCallback type isn't `void(*)()` it is `void(*)(char *message, double message_type)` so when it is called as a `void(*)()` parameters can have any value  and can't be used

Comment: Are you refereing to 'void (*cbPtr)() = NULL', which should be void (*cbPtr)(char *message, double message_type) = NULLl ? Isn't it strange that function only eventually crashes? This sounds more like a bug that would not run the script at all...

Comment: @DaanvS it isn't weird, argument will have random values and you have a precondition check that will return on NULL but a pointer can be wrong without being null

Comment: also i don't know the prototype of Register_Callback and how it uses its 
callback so i can just say what i think is weird

Comment: unfortunately no luck :(

Comment: do you have documentation on Register_Callback

Comment: all documentation is available on https://github.com/DanielHalpert/FXCM-MATLAB and  https://github.com/fxcm/ForexConnectAPI. Note: for the purpose of simplifying the case here, I changed fc_mexcallback to fruit_mexcallback, which can be found here https://github.com/DanielHalpert/FXCM-MATLAB/blob/master/fc_matlab_run/fc_mexCallback.c